# Avoid code-duplication while access different classes' static members in Java

Tags: java, oop, java-6

I'm writing an abstract class and have some sub-classes extend it. I have the exact same method with the same implementation in the sub-classes, and I'm wondering if there's a way to avoid the code duplication. The problem is that although the code is completely identical in every class, it uses a static variable of the class. Is there a way to have the method written only once (in the abstract class, for example) and have the method access the static member "`NAME`" from the class type of the current object?

In other words, is there a way to implement the method `getName()` only once, and return the `NAME` static variable of the current type of class?

```
public abstract class Car {
    public abstract String getName();
}

public class Bus extends car{
    
    private static final String NAME = "Bus a Bus A";
    
    public String getName() {
        return Bus.NAME;
    }
}

public class Taxi extends car{

    private static final String NAME = "TAXiiii";

    public String getName() {
        return Taxi.NAME;
    }
}

public class Motor extends car{

    private static final String NAME = "motor hehe";

    public String getName() {
        return Motor.NAME;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can avoid code duplication by simply removing the static final field. Just do `public String getName() { return "Bus a Bus A"; }`. Static fields with identical names aren't reusable in any sane way (i.e. they are not related in any meaningful name, just like private methods aren't).

Comment: Java 6? Really?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply pass the name to the super constructor? Although this removes the need for `Car` to be `abstract`, because you can simply return the name from its `getName` method instead.

```
public class Car {
    private final String name;
    
    public Car(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

public class Bus extends Car {

    private static final String NAME = "Bus a Bus A";

    public Bus() {
        super(NAME);
    }
}

public class Taxi extends Car {

    private static final String NAME = "TAXiiii";

    public Taxi() {
        super(NAME);
    }
}


public class Motor extends Car {

    private static final String NAME = "motor hehe";

    public Motor() {
        super(NAME);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that It makes sense to have the upper class as an abstract class, and for now all classes do not have constructors becuase it isn't necessary.

Comment: You only need an abstract class if your child classes implement different functionality. In your example, you would use your classes like `Car c = new Bus(); c.getName();`. The code and behaviour doesn't change, when you move the common code to the parent class like in my example. What you gain instead is more maintainability because you only need to change one place (the parent class) instead of multiple classes (all child classes)

Comment: I see your point now. The only thing that bothers me with your suggestion is the hold of NAME as car's data member and not static member, although it could and should be static

Comment: If `Car` had a `static` member called `NAME`, it would be the same value for all instances of `Car`. Why does it bother you? Why should it be static? In your example a car's name is dependent on its child implementations, so it cannot be `static`.

Comment: Do you need the subclasses at all? This could be an example for "favour composition over inheritance"...